# How do you connect a Nokia n810 Internet Tablet to WPA with PEAP and MSCHAPv2?

Tags: wifi, nokia, peap, hardware

We have a wireless network that's using PEAP and MSCHAPv2 for authentication.

Linux connects fine, but on a Nokia n810 Internet Tablet I get this error:

```
No CA certificates available to validate server certificate
```

I've set the "use manual user name" field in the advanced PEAP settings of the connection, and I also have no certificates in the Certificate Manager in Control Panel.

Does anyone know how to extract a certificate from whatever software provides it, and how to get that on to a Nokia device? I imagine I can just put it on a public-facing website, and download the file somehow. What file extension is a certificate supposed to be, usually?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the tablet.

As I understand it, PEAP normally uses certificates. You may need to ask your network admin to generate one for you. Once that it done, you should be able to install it in your device and use it.

However, if the problem turns out to be a lack of standard CA certificates in your tablet, you can extract the common ones from almost any linux web-server installation. They are usually in the `/etc/ssl` or `/etc/tls` directory or something like that.

Comment: Actually I found out that Maemo's software is buggy and doesn't add certificates properly. So no certificate authentication for WLAN will work at all...